# Unable to show confirm and alerts InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, cordova, iframe, inappbrowser, confirm

I'm wrapping an existing Webapp inside a Cordova project.

My Cordova project is simply an index.html that check Internet and VPN connection and, if OK, opens app.html that contains an iframe that loads the URL of the webapp.

That webapp have a 'Sign out' button with a confirm that i'm unable to show...

I tried to override it but no possitve results:

My **app.html**

```
<html>
    <head>    
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>TestApp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://test/myapp/index.jsp" 
        sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-scripts"
        style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"></iframe>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My **app.js**

```
(function () {
        window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
        addWebViewListeners();
})();

function addWebViewListeners() {
    window.alert = function (message, callback, title, buttonName) {
        if (null == title) {
            title = "Alerta";
        }
        if (null == buttonName) {
            title = "Aceptar";
        }
        navigator.notification.alert(message, callback, title, buttonName);
    };

    window.confirm = function (message, callback, title, buttonLabels) {
        if (null == title) {
            title = "Confirmación";
        }
        if (null == buttonLabels) {
            title = "[Aceptar,Cancelar]";
        }
        navigator.notification.confirm(message, callback, title, buttonLabels);
    };
}
```

**Function that loads app.html**

```
[onDeviceReady]
window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;

[onClickButton]
function goToApp() {
   window.open('iframe.html', '_self', 'location=no;toolbar=no;');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

InAppBrowser runs its own view, it is not part of the main app's webview.
If you wish to add code to the content displayed in InAppBrowser, you will need to use executeScript.

The code sample below will show an alert every time the loadstop event is fired.

```
myWindow = window.open('https://www.google.com', "_blank", "location=yes,hidden=no,closebuttoncaption=Close");
myWindow.addEventListener("loadstop", 
    function (e) {
        myWindow.executeScript({
            code: "(function() { alert('hello'); })()"
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: yes, I know it and your code works, but this is not my problem. I'm loading a webapp inside my InAppBrowser. This webapp shows alerts and confirms but but I'm unable to override incoming alerts into my custom alert to show it.